# How do I detect the user unlocking the device but not if notification center is simply shown like Dropbox and 1Password?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to implement a password screen on my app. Dropbox and 1Password's iPhone apps do this. When you leave and come back it will lock the app, and this also works for if the app is active and you lock the device and unlock it - the password screen will show.

My thought was to use `applicationDidBecomeActive` but this triggers in asinine cases, like just pulling down Notification Center, which shouldn't lock the app, nor does it in Dropbox or 1Password.

How are they accomplishing this?

Comment: I'd suggest implementing all of the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods and add log statements to each one. Then try all of the various combinations of actions and see what log output you get. See what is different for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what they're actually leveraging is the kSecAttrAccessible attributes of Keychain services, possibly kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked in this case, to get this behavior in Dropbox and 1Password.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/

I don't think you'll be able to get that information via the app delegate's methods directly. You'll want to combine what you know about the app becoming active from the app delegate with the security attributes available to the keychain.